# NativeScript Sample App takes 2.36 seconds just to see simple changes

Tags: nativescript

Checking NativeScript.
Created Sample android App only. No new files added. 
Just changing colors

```
<color name="ns_primary">#2196F3</color>    
<color name="ns_primaryDark">#1565C0</color>
```

and running **`tns run android`** takes *`Total time: 2 mins 26.62 secs`* to see my changes. Because `livesync` not working for `app\App_Resources\Android\values\colors.xml` and msg me to rebuild.

**Am I running wrong command just to see the changes?**

Using `Microsoft Android Emulator`

```
λ tns run android
Executing before-prepare hook from E:\Development\Mobile\NativeScript\todo-app\hooks\before-prepare\nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Found peer TypeScript 1.8.10
Project successfully prepared (android)

:config phase:  createDefaultIncludeFiles
        +found plugins: tns-core-modules-widgets

:config phase:  createPluginsConfigFile
         Creating product flavors include.gradle file in E:\Development\Mobile\NativeScript\todo-app\platforms\android/configurations folder...

:config phase:  pluginExtend
        +applying configuration from: E:\Development\Mobile\NativeScript\todo-app\platforms\android\configurations\include.gradle
        +applying configuration from: E:\Development\Mobile\NativeScript\todo-app\platforms\android\configurations\tns-core-modules-widgets\include.gradle

:config phase:  copyAarDependencies

:config phase:  addAarDependencies
        +adding dependency: E:\Development\Mobile\NativeScript\todo-app\platforms\android\libs\aar\widgets-release.aar
Observed package id 'system-images;android-15;default;armeabi-v7a' in inconsistent location 'E:\Libraries\android-sdk-windows\system-images\android-15\armeabi-v7a' (Expected 'E:\Libraries\android-sdk-windows\system-images\android-15\default\armeabi-v7a')
Observed package id 'system-images;android-19;default;armeabi-v7a' in inconsistent location 'E:\Libraries\android-sdk-windows\system-images\android-19\armeabi-v7a' (Expected 'E:\Libraries\android-sdk-windows\system-images\android-19\default\armeabi-v7a')
Observed package id 'system-images;android-23;default;armeabi-v7a' in inconsistent location 'E:\Libraries\android-sdk-windows\system-images\android-23\armeabi-v7a' (Expected 'E:\Libraries\android-sdk-windows\system-images\android-23\default\armeabi-v7a')
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preF0DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkF0DebugManifest
:preF0ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareTodoappRuntimeUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareWidgetsReleaseLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareF0DebugDependencies
:compileF0DebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileF0DebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateF0DebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:cleanLocalAarFiles
:ensureMetadataOutDir
:collectAllJars
:setProperties
:asbg:generateInterfaceNamesList
:asbg:runAstParser
inputDir: E:\Development\Mobile\NativeScript\todo-app\platforms\android\src\main\assets\app
                                                                                            outFile: ../bindings.txt
                                                                                              :asbg:generateBindings
:mergeF0DebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:compileF0DebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:generateF0DebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeF0DebugAssets
:generateF0DebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateF0DebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeF0DebugResources
:processF0DebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processF0DebugResources
:generateF0DebugSources
:incrementalF0DebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:compileF0DebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:compileF0DebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:compileF0DebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:buildMetadata UP-TO-DATE
:prePackageMarkerForF0Debug
:transformClassesWithDexForF0Debug UP-TO-DATE
:mergeF0DebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForF0Debug UP-TO-DATE
:processF0DebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForF0Debug UP-TO-DATE
:validateDebugSigning
:packageF0Debug
:zipalignF0Debug
:assembleF0Debug
:assembleDebug
:buildapk

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2 mins 26.62 secs
Project successfully built
Successfully deployed on device with identifier 'xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:5555'.
JS: Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you by any chance using Angular + NativeScript, if so the slow build is due to the amount of JavaScript files Angular 2 ships with. In order for {N} to provide full direct access to native APIs it parses any JavaScript file and looks for such calls during build time. This of course can lead to slower build if there are lot of js files in your node_modules or app folders.

There was a github issue logged about this at the [NativeScript repo](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript) and there where a lot of ideas how the team can handle this but it is very much still in progress and Angular 2 is not jet released so stay tuned.

Comment: @ladimir-amiorkov, Thanks. Stopped working on it. Looking into another option.